# how can I make pdf with codeigniter?

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, fpdf

so it can look like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BdzJ.png)

what tutorial should I follow?

Comment: I want that the blue words should come from oracle database. but I have not found a way. what tutorial should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the TCPDF file from [here](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf)
2. Extract and place the folder as 'tcpdf' in the path **“application/third_party”**
3. Create a file named 'pdf.php' in the folder **“application/libraries”** and put the below code

   ```
   <?php
   if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
   exit('No direct script access allowed');

   require_once APPPATH . "/third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";
   class Pdf extends tcpdf {
       public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. Add the following function in your controller

   ```
       public function createPDF($fileName,$html) {
           ob_start(); 
           // Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
           $this->load->library('Pdf');
           // create new PDF document
           $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
           // set document information
           $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
           $pdf->SetAuthor('TcPdf');
           $pdf->SetTitle('TcPdf');
           $pdf->SetSubject('TcPdf');
           $pdf->SetKeywords('TcPdf');

           // set default header data
           $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

           // set header and footer fonts
           $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
           $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

           $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
           $pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);

           // set default monospaced font
           $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

           // set margins
           $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 0, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
           $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(0);
           $pdf->SetFooterMargin(0);

           // set auto page breaks
           //$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
           $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);

           // set image scale factor
           $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

           // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
           if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
               require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
               $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
           }       

           // set font
           $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

           // add a page
           $pdf->AddPage();

           // output the HTML content
           $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

           // reset pointer to the last page
           $pdf->lastPage();       
           ob_end_clean();
           //Close and output PDF document
           $pdf->Output($fileName, 'F');        
       }
   ```
5. Crete a view exactly how you want in the pdf and load it in the controller to make pdf

   ```
       $htmlContent = $this->load->view('views/your-view-file', $data, TRUE);       
       $createPDFFile = 'your-pdf-name'.'.pdf';
       $this->createPDF('location-for-pdf'.$createPDFFile, $htmlContent);
   ```

This will create a pdf file exactly like the view you made, in the location you gave.